# Check for property values in array of objects

Tags: javascript

I have this array:

```
var data= [{IsNormal:"true", Name:"Mike"},
         {IsNormal:"true", Name:"Tom"},
         {IsNormal:"false", Name:"Clause"},
         {IsNormal:"true", Name:"Timm"},
         {IsNormal:"true", Name:"Marta"},
         {IsNormal:"true", Name:"Dora"}];
```

I need to write function to check if at least one of the objects in array has property IsNormal equal to false, if there is function must return false otherwise it must return true.

Here is my implementation:

```
    function chekStatus(data) {
        _.each(inspections, function (value, key) {
            if (!value.IsNormal)
                return false;
            return true;
        });
    }
```

but I want to write something more elegant using array prototype javascript fuctions.

Answer (score 3):

Use Array.some

```
 function chekStatus(data) {
     return data.some(function (item) { return !item.IsNormal; })
 }
```

Note, `IsNormal` values should be `boolean`, not `string`

```
var data= [{IsNormal:true, Name:"Mike"},
     {IsNormal: true, Name:"Tom"},
     {IsNormal: false, Name:"Clause"},
     {IsNormal: true, Name:"Timm"},
     {IsNormal: true, Name:"Marta"},
     {IsNormal: true, Name:"Dora"}];
```

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/777n3vwz/)

Comment: it's awayes return true!

Comment: @Michael the code works like a charm if data are boolean. In your example you have IsNormal that is a string, so you need to do `return item.IsNormal === "false"`

Comment: here is row:

 object.IsServiceable = inspectionReviews.some(function (item) { return !item.IsNormal });

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Array.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

```
data.some(obj => !obj.IsNormal)
```

Comment: this sign not recognized =>

Comment: @Michael then the other answer, that is equal but doesn't use ES6, should work